# Same ArrayList but different object-order

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Helly guys,

I have a little Question about ArrayLists. I´m writing an android app (a kind of music player) with Android Studio and therefore I have a MainActivity, a second Activity for the informations about the current song and a Service for the music.

My problem now is, that I give the Service a list of the Songs, which the Service should play und i give the second Activity the same list via DataHolder for displaying the informations of the songs.

But the lists have not the same order. Can someone tell me why and how to fix this?

Here some Code:

Here I define the ArrayList. I want to have an random order, so i shuffle it one time. In checkRunTimePermission, the list get filled.

```
songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        checkRunTimePermission();
        Collections.shuffle(songList);
```

Here I start the Service and send the list to the Service and the second Activity

```
public void pureRandomClick (Button pureRandomButton) {
        pureRandomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bkgrSrv.setList(songList);
                bkgrSrv.pureRandom(max, min);
                DataHolder holder = (DataHolder) getApplicationContext();
                holder.setSongList(songList);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, playScreen.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my DataHolder class

```
public class DataHolder extends Application {

    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    public ArrayList<Song> getSonglist() {return songList;}
    public void setSongList (ArrayList<Song> data) {this.songList = data;}

}
```

Comment: It looks like something is missing.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's more work for you, but you might find the solution while doing it and it will be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this solution ?

```
public void setSongList (ArrayList<Song> data) {
   this.songList.addAll(data);

 }
```

Comment: ArrayList is a sequential list. So, insertion and retrieval order is the same.
So to put list on you dataholder you can try to use addAll or you can add each element like that : 

public void setSongList (ArrayList<Song> data) {
for(Song song: data)   
this.songList.add(song);

 }

Comment: When I use addAll, the app crashing.

Comment: You need just to instanciate your object before.